# Ordering laravel form::select by already selected values

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to order the form list by previously already selected values? these values are already selected when the page is loaded.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Role:</strong>
        {!! Form::select('roles[]', $roles, $userRole, array('class' => 'form-control form','multiple')) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

Outputs my list with the values in a non ordered fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to order the list because it is essentially an select list with options, which makes it impossible to order automatically based in value.

Answer (score 0):

Your select is populated with data from `$roles` variable, I think that you should have ordered your list in that variable before render the template.